# How to update only the named view using UI-Router

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am creating a web app to help students in science, history and math. When you first land on the site I have a home/landing page. When you click get started I route to /exam/instructions. Each of my steps instructions, math and science our templates that I load into the `ui-view="exam-detail"`. Currently the whole `ui-view` loads when I navigate to and from instructions through sciences. Ideally I simply want an area for pagination and an area for the subject matter and only want the `ui-view="exam-detail"` to update with the correct template.

I have not used UI-Router at all and any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

index.html

```
<div ui-view></div>
```

state-exam>exam.html

```
<div class="state-exam">
    <nav ui-view="exam-pagination"></nav>
    <section ui-view="exam-detail"></section>
</div>
```

route.js

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
.module('studentPortal')
.config(routeConfig);

function routeConfig($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$stateProvider
  .state('home', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'app/main/main.html',
    controller: 'MainController',
    controllerAs: 'main'
  })

  .state('exam', {
    url: '/exam/:step',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'app/state-exam/exam.html',
    controller: 'ExamController',
    controllerAs: 'examController',
  })

  .state('exam.instructions', {
    url: '/instructions',
    views: {
      'exam-pagination':{
        templateUrl: 'app/state-exam/exam-pagination.html'
      },
      'exam-detail' : {
        templateUrl: 'app/state-exam/exam-instructions.html'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('exam.math', {
    url: '/math',
    views: {
      'exam-pagination':{
        templateUrl: 'app/state-exam/exam-pagination.html'
      },
      'exam-detail' : {
        templateUrl: 'app/state-exam/exam-math.html'
      }
    }
  });
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
  }

})();
```

Comment: what you can simply do is you create navigation as a seperate directive and  include it in master.html rather then having it as a ui-view

Comment: @maddygoround, thanks yeah I think I was over thinking it. That works. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/aR3cdYrDEY7FJvhLPRCj?p=preview)

There is a similar Q & A in fact, with working plunker:

#### [Angular UI Router - Nested States with multiple layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25667660/1679310)

Solution here, is to move the *static* view from child to parent. It won't be reloaded for each child *(view is reloaded only if parent state is changed)*. We will use **absolute** naming *(see included links for more details)*

So this is the code adjustment

```
.state('exam', {
    url: '/exam/:step',
    abstract: true,
    // the root view and the static pagination view
    // will be defined here, so we need views : {}
    views: {
      '':{
        templateUrl: 'app/state-exam/exam.html',
        controller: 'ExamController',
        controllerAs: 'examController',
      },
      // absolute naming targets the view defined above
      'exam-pagination@exam':{
        templateUrl: 'app/state-exam/exam-pagination.html'
      },
    }
  })

  .state('exam.instructions', {
    url: '/instructions',
    views: {
      // 'exam-pagination':{}, // defined in parent
      'exam-detail' : {
        templateUrl: 'app/state-exam/exam-instructions.html'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('exam.math', {
    url: '/math',
    views: {
      // 'exam-pagination':{}, // defined in parent
      'exam-detail' : {
        templateUrl: 'app/state-exam/exam-math.html'
      }
    }
  });
```

Also check this to get more details about absolute view naming

- [Angular UI router nested views](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25587280/1679310)
- [Angular-UI Router: Nested Views Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29585103/1679310)

The [working example is here](http://plnkr.co/edit/aR3cdYrDEY7FJvhLPRCj?p=preview)

Comment: Well, maybe here is the reason why, explained even better [How do I prevent reload on named view, when state changes? AngularJS UI-Router](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23568908/1679310)

Comment: Radim, Is the the first object inside of views supposed to be ' ' empty? I moved <nav ui-view="exam-pagination"></nav> to the parent but when I use 'exam-pagination@exam' like in your example the pagination does not load. If I remove the @exam it loads

Comment: Well, the *exam.html* is injected into index.html ui-view="" (unnamed). It contains targets for child state *ui-view="exam-detail"* and also for sister view `ui-view="exam-pagination"`. Because this target is filled by this (exam) state, we need to use absolute naming... so the second view must be 'exam-pagination@exam' - to target view name *exam-pagination* inside of the stat *exam* === *exam-pagination@exam*. Does it help?

Comment: There is a link to working plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/aR3cdYrDEY7FJvhLPRCj?p=preview, hope that could help to see that in action