# Accessing child state parameters in parent in Angular UI-Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have the following state configuration. How can I get `id` parameters in `index` state `@` view so that it could be accessible by both, `left` and `detail` views controllers? Now if I try to access it via `$state.params.id` it is undefined, but if I `console.log($state)` I can see the parameter in my console. I only need the parameter if available on first load of left view.

```
$stateProvider
    .state('index', {
        url: '/',
        views: {
           '@' : {
               template: '/**/'
               resolve: {
                   params: function ($state) {
                       return $state.params.id;
                   }
               }
           },
           'left@index' : {
               template: '/**/',
               controller: 'AppController',
               controllerAs: 'app'
           },
           'main@index' : { 
               template: '/**/'
           }
     })
     .state('index.detail', {
         url: '/:id',
         views: {
             'detail@index' : {
                 template: '/**/',
                 controller: 'DetailController',
                 controllerAs: 'detail',
              }
         }
});
```

Comment: It simply does not make sense. Parent params can be consumed in children, but not vice versa. Check e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/24301754/1679310

Comment: I need that the left view  also get the id parameter, without reinitializing its controller

Comment: But how would that view know about it WITHOUT re-init controller? Will you use watching? that is against the principle of the UI-Router. Rather create more named view and let them update when child param is changing. E.g. check here layout style http://stackoverflow.com/q/25667660/1679310 - which could be used here as well

Comment: Here is what you need http://stackoverflow.com/q/32448285/1679310 ... try to observe the tricke with parent view, and children updating that (having access to the params if provided)

Comment: My bad, I only need the parameter on first load of controller of left view